# How to divide a specific number in a list?

Tags: python, math, numbers, theory

A Mersenne Prime follows this formula 2^n-1.  I have created a new type of factoring method for numbers which do not produce Mersenne primes.  It is very abstract.  Its premise is if a specific number is applied using modular math and the new number becomes (zero), it is not a Mersenne Prime Number.  I submitted a paper to The Journal of Number Theory online, however it was rejected by the journal.  I have attached it if you would like to look it over,  I still feel my method is promising yet I'm no coding expert. [This is a pdf I sent to the Journal of Number Theory](https://frenchvoynich.files.wordpress.com/2020/01/jnth-d-19-00821-3.pdf)  My problem is in my new code I don't know how to divide a number in the list.  The list enumerates ok yet I want to subtract z=11 from 253 which equals 242 than mod it by 121, however when I create a range from 1-254  I cannot seem to do this math.  The reason I'm interested in this is 253//11=23 which is a factor of 2^11-1.  I got this idea from a ratio page.

Type 1:11 and the second number is a 22 just add 1 and its 23.

Check it out
https://goodcalculators.com/ratio-calculator/

The formula will target any number in the range and what I'm looking for is a zero.

Additional details for grismar as per request:

Grismar and others,

What I have found is that Mersenne primes will produce fewer zero's below the number 11 vs.  a number like 2^11-1.  Also when you output the number by subtraction of z and then mod z*z you may find the number with the lowest factor in it after you divide it by z.  The range must be large enough as to find that number, yet if is zero simply divide by z.  Then for instance when you find 23 by dividing 11 into 253.  You can divide 23 into 2047 and you should get 89.  More than likely if you use a different number to check this factor you will get a fraction.  So when checking using this method when you find a zero for a number which does not produce a Mersenne Prime number like.  Lets pick 29.  536870911   ÷   233 = 2304167 so you get a factor number not a fraction.

These are all the factors of 536870911
[1, 233, 1103, 256999, 2089, 486737, 2304167, 536870911]

If you would like even more details leave a comment please.

Programmer in learning looking for help here is my program:
1 should be the start range!

```
    while True:
        x = int(input("Use 1 for the start range to make this work correctly: 
    "))
        i = int(input("End Range: "))
        z = int(input("square of  primes multiplied by a number plus z which 
    does not make a 
    mersenne prime, this finds its factor of z: "))
        fact = [(i + 1, x) for i, x in enumerate(range(x, i))]



    print([((int(i)-z) % (z*z)) if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in fact])
```

Comment: so you want to apply this calculation `(i - z) % z` to every element in `fact`?

Comment: Hi, I want to apply this to the entire list.  (int(i)-z) % (z*z).  So if I type in 1-254 range. 253 will become zero.  While using z=11.

Comment: when you say `i`, you mean the `end range` value, or the `0` index element in each tuple of `fact`? Try not to use the same variables for everything, because it gets messy.

Comment: I find it very unclear what you are trying to do. There are too many things in your code that don't make any sense to me. I would suggest a good basic Python tutorial. Btw, your manuscript has much more severe problems than a missing proof-of-concept implementation. Try to contact a nearby university's math department and ask if they could take a look at the proposal and if they would be interested in jointly publishing the work. But be prepared to be told that there is nothing publishable there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding taking it to a University Nico.

Comment: Nico's advice is generally sound, but having just read your paper @Edward you can probably save yourself the trouble. What you're achieving is not actually new, it's merely a specific implementation (which may or may not be novel, my bet is not) of well known aspects of these numbers. Part of scientific research is studying the work of others so you can ensure your idea is novel - a university education, or at least some professional guidance on research and publishing can go a long way if you're interested in contributing. As for your actual Python question: that's unclear, please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks Grismar, I will add some details to the initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you are trying is this, the `int` call is unnecessary since the values are `integers` from the start. Also, don't use the same variable `i` for different purposes:

```py
calculations = [
    (index + 1, (fact_tuple[0] - z) % (z*z)) for index, fact_tuple in enumerate(fact)
]
print(calculations) # with x = 1, i = 254, z = 11
>>> [(1, 111), (2, 112), (3, 113), (4, 114), (5, 115), (6, 116), (7, 117), (8, 118), (9, 119), (10, 120), (11, 0), (12, 1), (13, 2), (14, 3), (15, 4), (16, 5), (17, 6), (18, 7), (19, 8), (20, 9), (21, 10), (22, 11), (23, 12), (24, 13), (25, 14), (26, 15), (27, 16), (28, 17), (29, 18), (30, 19), (31, 20), (32, 21), (33, 22), (34, 23), (35, 24), (36, 25), (37, 26), (38, 27), (39, 28), (40, 29), (41, 30), (42, 31), (43, 32), (44, 33), (45, 34), (46, 35), (47, 36), (48, 37), (49, 38), (50, 39), (51, 40), (52, 41), (53, 42), (54, 43), (55, 44), (56, 45), (57, 46), (58, 47), (59, 48), (60, 49), (61, 50), (62, 51), (63, 52), (64, 53), (65, 54), (66, 55), (67, 56), (68, 57), (69, 58), (70, 59), (71, 60), (72, 61), (73, 62), (74, 63), (75, 64), (76, 65), (77, 66), (78, 67), (79, 68), (80, 69), (81, 70), (82, 71), (83, 72), (84, 73), (85, 74), (86, 75), (87, 76), (88, 77), (89, 78), (90, 79), (91, 80), (92, 81), (93, 82), (94, 83), (95, 84), (96, 85), (97, 86), (98, 87), (99, 88), (100, 89), (101, 90), (102, 91), (103, 92), (104, 93), (105, 94), (106, 95), (107, 96), (108, 97), (109, 98), (110, 99), (111, 100), (112, 101), (113, 102), (114, 103), (115, 104), (116, 105), (117, 106), (118, 107), (119, 108), (120, 109), (121, 110), (122, 111), (123, 112), (124, 113), (125, 114), (126, 115), (127, 116), (128, 117), (129, 118), (130, 119), (131, 120), (132, 0), (133, 1), (134, 2), (135, 3), (136, 4), (137, 5), (138, 6), (139, 7), (140, 8), (141, 9), (142, 10), (143, 11), (144, 12), (145, 13), (146, 14), (147, 15), (148, 16), (149, 17), (150, 18), (151, 19), (152, 20), (153, 21), (154, 22), (155, 23), (156, 24), (157, 25), (158, 26), (159, 27), (160, 28), (161, 29), (162, 30), (163, 31), (164, 32), (165, 33), (166, 34), (167, 35), (168, 36), (169, 37), (170, 38), (171, 39), (172, 40), (173, 41), (174, 42), (175, 43), (176, 44), (177, 45), (178, 46), (179, 47), (180, 48), (181, 49), (182, 50), (183, 51), (184, 52), (185, 53), (186, 54), (187, 55), (188, 56), (189, 57), (190, 58), (191, 59), (192, 60), (193, 61), (194, 62), (195, 63), (196, 64), (197, 65), (198, 66), (199, 67), (200, 68), (201, 69), (202, 70), (203, 71), (204, 72), (205, 73), (206, 74), (207, 75), (208, 76), (209, 77), (210, 78), (211, 79), (212, 80), (213, 81), (214, 82), (215, 83), (216, 84), (217, 85), (218, 86), (219, 87), (220, 88), (221, 89), (222, 90), (223, 91), (224, 92), (225, 93), (226, 94), (227, 95), (228, 96), (229, 97), (230, 98), (231, 99), (232, 100), (233, 101), (234, 102), (235, 103), (236, 104), (237, 105), (238, 106), (239, 107), (240, 108), (241, 109), (242, 110), (243, 111), (244, 112), (245, 113), (246, 114), (247, 115), (248, 116), (249, 117), (250, 118), (251, 119), (252, 120), (253, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Marcos,  the list lost its enumeration and it doesn't seem to be in order is there any way you can help make it print out differently?

Comment: Thanks a million 0 and 1's :) Marcos.

Comment: Another thing you have to start with 1 in the range in order to make it work and allow the range for the 2nd input to find the number for factors